# How to display the image repeatedly from the url in android volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I want to make a recent post with pictures, from json data below:

```
{
  "movie": {
    "totalResults": {
      "data": "16"
    },
    "start": {
      "data": "1"
    },
    "perPage": {
      "data": "2"
    },
    "post": [
      {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "data": "Title 1"
        },
        "mediaThumbnail": {
          "url": "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/image1.jpg",
          "height": "72",
          "width": "72"
        },
        "summary": {
          "type": "text",
          "data": "Description"
        }
      },
      {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "data": "Title 2"
        },
        "mediaThumbnail": {
          "url": "https://1.bp.blogspot.com/image2.jpg",
          "height": "72",
          "width": "72"
        },
        "summary": {
          "type": "text",
          "data": "Description"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want to use android volley. But if from friends all there who have other alternatives, in addition to using android volley. Friends can suggest it to me.
Thanks

Comment: [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/) is networking library cannot use for image processing. You can use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for image loading.

Comment: @MohamedMohaideenAH Ok, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using android Volly you can use Glide library,
like this

```
Glide.with(context)
   .load("http://inthecheesefactory.com/uploads/source/glidepicasso/cover.jpg")
   .into(ivImg);
```

Glide uses RGB_565 since it consumed just 50% memory footprint compared to ARGB_8888 used by other libs by default.

For showing a list of pictures you can use recycler view with an image views as an row element which you can set with the glide in the adapter.